# Repeated errors will cause Forever to stop restarting node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, forever

I am running a node.js server as a backend for a client side Javascript application and we are using Forever to launch the node.js app.

A bug has been discovered in the client code that provides an incorrect path when trying to open a file (because of case insensitivity in our current server). The error is not properly handled and this causes node.js crash. The first few times this occurs Forever sucessfully relaunched the app but after repeatedly triggering the error Forever will fail to bring the app back up and we get a 502 bad gateway error when trying to goto any of the server pages.

Here is the unhandled error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'public/projects/testHoc7/hocProject121/agents/agent1/index.agent'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at Object.editAgentXML [as edit_agent_XML] (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/project.js:699:5)
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/project.js:313:30
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/query.js:159:5
    at Cursor.nextObject (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:742:5)
    at commandHandler (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:716:14)
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1847:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:445:41)
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:478:18
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #8

/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:245
        throw message;
```

and here is the log message we get when Forever fails to restart the app:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'public/projects/testHoc7/hocProject121/agents/agent1/index.agent'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at Object.editAgentXML [as edit_agent_XML] (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/project.js:699:5)
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/project.js:313:30
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection/query.js:159:5
    at Cursor.nextObject (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:742:5)
    at commandHandler (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:716:14)
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1847:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:445:41)
    at /srv/AgentCubesOnline/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:478:18
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8

/usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/node_modules/broadway/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js:283
          throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                         ^
Error: Cannot stop process that is not running.
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/forever-monitor/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js:332:26
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

We will of course fix the bug and add proper error handling but I am currently more interested in finding out how to prevent Forever from failing. What could cause Forever to stop bringing node.js back?

Comment: Do you really just expect it to keep restarting your app over and over and over indefinitely just filling up the log files?  If an app fails to start N times (where N is a reasonable number), it seems unlikely it's going to start the N+1 time.

Comment: @jfriend00 Well it wasn't really failing to start, the error was triggered from a user interaction and it was only 8 times which doesn't seem like a completely unreasonable number of times to restart. I am using pm2 and it seems to restart every time without issue now so maybe that will be a good solution.

Comment: If it was successfully restarting, then you can shorten the `--minUptime` option so that `forever` considers it successfully started before the bad user interaction happens.  I looked in the `forever` source and I don't see any limitations on how many times it restarts.

Comment: @jfriend00 isn't that why they're called FOREVER to begin with? XD